# When netty channelfuture's status can become uncompleted?

Tags: netty

In our production system, I can see the below can happen on a netty ChannelFuture:

After channelfuture.awaitUninterruptibly(10 seconds) return, both channelfuture.isDone() and channelfuture.isSuccess() return false. I am wondering in what case this can happen?

The channelfuture is attached a message sending operation (client side). Tcpdump shows that the window size of the server side is 0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It means you waited for 10 seconds but the ChannelFuture was still not complete. Which means the operation was not success or failed yet.

Comment: Thanks. If the operation was not success or failed yet, why channelfuture.awaitUninterruptibly return? Document mentioned that if it timeout, it should completed with failure.

Comment: Because you tell it to wait max 10 seconds ... Please see the api docs.

Comment: Hi Norman, I guess you misunderstood me. If it returns because if timeout(10 seconds), its status should be like this: hannelfuture.isDone() == true and channelfuture.isSuccess() == false. But what i am asking is why both of them return false!!

Comment: No I not missunderstood you... isDone will only be true once its "done" because of an success or error. Like I said read the api docs

Comment: Both channelfuture.isDone() and channelfuture.isSuccess() return false. The api docs says that if it is timeout, hannelfuture.isDone() == TRUE. I am wondering why it CAN return if it is still not completed.